# TensorFlow MNIST example feeding own images

Tags: tensorflow, mnist

I am trying to learn TensorFlow, so I was trying to understand their example with smaller dimensions. Suppose I have image1, image2, image3 three 28x28 matrices which hold grayscale values (0..255). image1 is the training image, image2 is the validation image, and image3 is the test image. I was trying to understand how I can feed my own images into the MNIST example they have [here](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/images/convnet_mnist.py).

I am particularly interested in replacing the following line with my own imageset:

```
X, Y, testX, testY = mnist.load_data(one_hot=True)
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your image is a numpy array, of shape `[1, 28, 28, 1]`.

You can just feed this numpy array to the node `X` or `textX`. Even though X is not a placeholder, you can provide its value to TensorFlow.

```py
X_value = ...  # numpy array
# ... same for Y_value, testX_value, testY_value

feed_dict = {X: X_value, Y: Y_value, testX: testX_value, testY: testY_value}
sess.run(train_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

`mnist.load_data(one_hot=True)` is nothing but some preprossesing of the data. If you have some images in hand, you can just make them an `ndarray` and feed into the graph. For examples if you have a node named `images`, you can feed the images using `feed_dict = {images: some_image}`.